# Arguments Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arguments

i'm currently learning js and need to pass a test, every requirement checks out besides "should work on an arguments object".

So I need to use arguments[0]or[1], its also necessary for me to check if the array is an array. Issue here is that for some reason the Array.isArray() part of the code turns my "should work on an arguments object" requirement false, even though I used arguments[0].

please try to ignore the rest of the code, there are also other requirements set. I know they seem kind of unnecessary to include.

this is my code:

```
function (array, n) {
  var resultArray = [];if (typeof arguments[1] !== "number" || arguments[1] == 0 || arguments[1] < 0){
  resultArray.push.call(resultArray, arguments[0][0])
  return resultArray
 } 
  else if (arguments[1] > arguments[0].length){
  return arguments[0] && array
 } else {
 return resultArray;
}
};
```

Comment: your code seems full of redundancies

Comment: but it works fine, i can't reproduce the issue

Comment: @skara9 its because there are other requirements I need to meet, I just didn't include them in here because the only part I dont get is why "if (Array.isArray(arguments[0]) !== true){
    return []} " is giving me a false in my "use arguments object" requirement

Comment: who/what is giving you the false, and how are they checking it?

Comment: @skara9 its my bootcamps website automatically checks it in the background, I dont know the exact way they check it unfortunately.

to me the code looks ready to go, every requirement is checked. if I take that line out the "use arguments object" requirement is green too so I know its giving me an error bc of the Array.isArray() line

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function simply

```
const first = (array = [], n = 1) =>
    Array.isArray(array) ? array.slice(0, array.length >= n ? n : 1) : [];
```

If `n > array.length` this will return the whole array.

Comment: hey, thanks for your help. however the function works, so the question in the comments in the first few lines is resolved.

its just that this line of code:

if (Array.isArray(arguments[0]) !== true){
    return []}

throws off my "use arguments object" requirement and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the requirements expects you use somewhere the variable argument `array`.  Instead you use `arguments[0]`.

So use the first over the latter.
Likewise, use `n` instead of `arguments[1]`

Comment: hey Roko, thanks for your help.

The issue is that its also a requirement to use arguments[0] and [1]

Comment: @Hey but than `array` and `n` make no sense at all.

Comment: in this case yes, but its a test so the parameters are given by them. I cant change that

Comment: @Hey if the named arguments `array` and `n` are given — than you're expected to use them, not to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
if (!window[atob('QXJyYXk=')][atob('aXNBcnJheQ==')](arguments[0])) return [];
```

Comment: issue could be arising from some kind of software thats flagging the string `Array.isArray`, so i thought it was worth testing